# Magento 2 - By default Magento provides a way to import sales orders?

Tags: magento2, orders, import

As the title says.

If I go to System > Import, it only shows import products, customers + its addresses, taxes, pricing but not orders.

Am I looking in the wrong place or Magento does not provide order import feature by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no feature to import orders. But if you want to import them from Magento 1, you can use the [data migration tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-tool.html)

Answer (score 0):

Some features Magento does not provide by default (otherwise how will it's partners and service providers will earn) :)

Although if you want to import orders from Magento 1.x store to 2.x store, then Magento has provided [data migration tools](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-tool.html), which will help you to migrate settings and data.

If this is not the case and you want to import orders from custom source, then there are many extensions available. Please have a look at below links:
http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-dataflow-batch-import-export-orders-to-csv.html
http://www.commerceextensions.com/dataflow-batch-import-export-orders-to-csv-magento-2.html
https://www.aitoc.com/en/magento_2_orders_export_and_import.html

Comment: Any free extension available?

Comment: No, till now there is no free extension available (at-least not in my knowledge).